# compare two files with numbers and find the difference , using linux shell command

Tags: linux, shell

```
8       13
10      22
13      24
22      26
24      27
26      28
27      29
28      32
29      34
32      35
34      40
66
78
```

I have two files like the above,file1 is the first column while file 2 is the second
and I want to get the difference between these two files
like 8 is in the first file but not in the second file
i used comm but the results are strange
how to achieve what I want?

Comment: do you mean the mathematical difference between the two columns, such that first row is 8-13=-5? Else please edit your question to include required sample output. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
man diff
```

Have a read of that, I'm sure it will do what you want.